# How addition of a soluble salt affects equilibrium involving precipitation with a base sharing the same cation?

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions

I have the following reaction at equilibrium:

$$\ce{Ba(NO3)2(aq) + KOH(aq) <=> Ba(OH)2(s) + 2 KNO3(aq)}$$

Will there be a change in the equilibrium if the salt $\ce{KCl}$ is added? Will the reaction shift in a certain direction to restore equilibrium?

I know that with adding $\ce{KCl}$, $\ce{K+}$ ions are added, but I am not sure if that is related to the answer.

Comment: Start by writing the net ionic equation.

Comment: And also balance your equation